# MySQL, display data not shown when using '=' command

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is there a way for me to also print out values not equal to each other?

I used a command:

```
WHERE displayname = personnel
```

I have 800+ data not shown, how can I show these data?

Note personnel and data are from two different tables.

My whole script looks like this:

```
SELECT a.something, a.somethins2, b.something1, b.something2
FROM a, b
WHERE a.displayname = b.personnel
```

Comment: Wrap personnel in single quote

Comment: are you trying to get the record that matched a.displayname = b.personnel and not matched from table a?

Answer (score 1):

`!=` is the "not equals" operator, so you could have a `WHERE displayname != personnel` clause. A full query would probably look like this:

```
SELECT displayname, personnel
FROM   some_table t1
JOIN   some_other_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  displayname != personnel
```

Comment: I already tried using the != operator, however it displays almost a billion data.

Comment: @NetITSysAdOJT Seems like you're missing a proper join condition, but it's really hard to answer a question like this. Can you edit your question to share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
select * from table_name1 t1,table_name2 t2 where 
column_name!='".$data."' 
and t2.id=t1.id
```

Comment: that is dynamic value i mean your post value

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get the record that matched a.displayname = b.personnel and not matched from table a:

```
SELECT a.something, a.somethins2, b.something1, b.something2
FROM a LEFT JOIN b
ON a.displayname = b.personnel
```